# Обработка post запроса json'ом c помощью flask

Tags: python, flask

Мне на определенный урл, например `http://hello/this_is/`, приходит `POST` запрос с `json`. Как мне получить этот `json` ? Использую `Flask`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разобрался. для этого есть специальный атрибут. Вот пример:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route(url, methods=['POST'])
def to_bot_message():
    json_string = request.json
```